# Cost pyramid around goal?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again,

**//edit**: question might be obsolete, see my first comment for reason

I'm just examining the local costmap of my robot. After giving it a 2D goal in `rviz` I see kind of a *cost pyramid* around the goal with the goal on its tip. That makes the robot struggle with getting to the goal as cost goes up the closer the goal gets.

Is that the usual behaviour of the costmap? If it is, what's the reason for this?

In `rviz` the cost pyramid looks like this, where the current goal is in the middle of the red area: [image: image description]

Thanks!

Cheers,
Hendrik

PS: it might be that I've not yet understood which cost indication color is low and which is high, but I assume red is high and violet is low. Correct me if I'm wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72385/cost-pyramid-around-goal?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, I think I have muddled up high and low cost in my understanding of how the point cloud is rendered.

---

Originally posted by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) with karma: 1145 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0